# WP7 - StaticResource Error?

Tags: windows-phone-7

It appears that this line that is within:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ItemReason" Text="{Binding Reason}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
```

Is triggering an error here:

```
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
```

I'm not quiet sure why.  Any ideas?

Comment: @SLaks - Thats a good question...  It breaks on the following line in the unhandledException sub: System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();  Is there a way to tell what the exception is?  All I know is that it works if I take out the Styles

Comment: To see the exception, look at the arguments to the UnhandledException handler in the debugger (named `e` in your case).

Comment: For an unhandled exception, the arguments usually won't do any good since those won't carry any meaningful information other that "An unhandled exception occurred." What's better to look at is the stack trace, that can show a possible error trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not defining the control style but rather the font size.

```
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}
```

This makes it right.

For future reference keep [this](http://ria.dzone.com/articles/pre-defined-system-styles-and) at hand.

Comment: That was it...  Why is it that when I was editing the file in VS2010 it allowed me to choose it as a style?

Comment: Usually Visual Studio doesn't suggest items after StaticResource when you are binding in XAML. It won't highlight an error because when a style is not found it is ignored till compile time.